# Use SSL in Netezza connection string

Tags: connection-string, netezza

I connect from SAS on Windows to Netezza and would like to set the connection string option **security level** to **only secured** as shown in the dialog box.  (I want to do it in the connection string so I don't have manually to click the option every time.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ODBC connection string specify "SecurityLevel=onlySecured" to force the use of SSL.

Comment: Thank you! By the why, where did you find that?  I couldn't find the documentation.

Comment: My first attempt was checking the "IBM Netezza ODBC, JDBC, and OLE DB
Installation and Configuration Guide" doc. While that ended up having a concrete example for perferredUnSecured, I actually "cheat" when I need a specific connection string example by creating a file DSN through the windows ODBC Data Source Administration tool, selecting the options I'm interested in, and then opening the resultant file in a text editor to see what it creates.